# Is it possible to declare CASE statement within Replace (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just as titled, is it possible?

So is like the following:

```
SELECT 
REPLACE ('Hello', 'e', '!')
REPLACE(
    CASE 
        WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'Hello'
        ELSE 'Bye'
    END AS MyStr, 'e', '!'
    )
```

Because it returns:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'CASE'.

Comment: @AdamRobinson I did, doesn't work.  So I wonder did I did something wrong on my syntax lol

Comment: "Doesn't work" can mean a lot of things. I see that you've edited your question to include the error message; thanks! Please be sure to provide information like that in future questions. The less you make other people try to guess the problem (did it give an error? Did it give you unexpected results? Did your computer catch fire?), the more likely you are to get a good answer.

Comment: @AdamRobinson sorry, forgot to include the error message.  Just addedl. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: Could you explain what you're doing here ??   Isn't the second part always gonna say 'Hello' because 1 = 1 always ??    If that's an example, how about something more realistic so as not to confuse slow people like me :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your query, but apart from that things look correct. It should be

```
SELECT 
REPLACE ('Hello', 'e', '!'), -- missing comma in the original query
REPLACE(
    CASE 
        WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'Hello'
        ELSE 'Bye'
    END, 'e', '!' -- removed the AS clause
    )
```